# How to disable Mac Login screen at boot time?

Tags: macos, mac, boot, osx-mountain-lion, login-screen

I bought a new Mac Mini in June, when i click the power it goes to login screen then i login then it boots up, i want it not to ask for the user/pass in this stage and ask later when the operating system has loaded like my mac book pro

Comment: I searched a lot i always get info about how to make it auto login and other stuff :s ....

Comment: Are both the mini and the MBP running the same OS?

Comment: Yes josh but Gordon answered and I think he is right

Comment: I do too Shereef :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you have FileVault encryption enabled (in System Preferences -> Security & Privacy pane -> FileVault tab). FileVault protects your files by encrypting the entire volume, which means you need to supply a password to decrypt & get access to it before it can load the operating system. If you don't want this, you need to turn off FileVault.

Comment: It looks like you are right, when I go to work I'll try to disable it and see what happens then I will mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

System Preferences -> General -> Untick "Disable Automatic Login"

I think that's what you're after.

Comment: Isn't that option in the `Users & Groups` preferences?  And if it is actually *ticked* (or chosen) that should already be the behavior the poster wants to have.

Comment: I already got what I am after, but thanks for your interest.